# Help understanding logical complement

Tags: logic

Does 
¬n → ¬(m ∨ k) equal

n → (m ∨ k)?

can we "cancel" out the complement/negation?

Comment: $$\text{It's not wet outside} \implies \text{it didn't rain}$$

But, that doesn't mean

$$\text{It's wet outside} \implies \text{it rained}$$

Perhaps someone decided to hose the yard ;).

Comment: It wasn't me @AlexClark, despite the fact that I'd love to hose the yard whenever I get the chance! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Like Jasper already told:
$$
\neg n \Rightarrow \neg(m \vee k) \iff \\
\neg (\neg n) \vee \neg (m \vee k) \iff \\
n \vee \neg(m \vee k)) \iff \\
\neg(m \vee k) \vee n \iff \\
(m \vee k) \Rightarrow n \iff \\
n \Leftarrow (m \vee k)
$$

Comment: Ouch, ouch. I corrected it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

No we cannot. An implication is not equivalent to its *inverse*, but is equivalent to its *contrapositive*.